# What does the following sentence mean [ From The Invisible Man , Ch 1 ]

Tags: sentence

I'm a little confused by the following sentence. I know all the nouns here, but I don't understand the phrase "a turn them bandages"

> What a turn them bandages did give me, to be sure!

Comment: Those bandages gave me quite a surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Turn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn)*: see definition 13b.  Here it means a surprise or shock.  And *them* here is dialect for *those*.

Comment: Yeah , now i know it's `them` that confused me, thanks.

Comment: Them thar colloquialisms can be just a mite vexin' to grok!